# Regex not working having reserved character in search text c#

Tags: c#, regex, character, reserved

I have a regular expression which was working for all my requirement until now, suddenly I  got a string which has reserved character like + in c++ and # in C#. Below code work for all my word collection except for c++ and C#

```
MatchCollection matches= Regex.Matches(@"This  program is written in C# We'll delete it after ten days", @"\bC\+\+\b");
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
      Console.Write(m.Value);
}
```

Can any one point out why?

Comment: @TimPietzcker actually it will not match `C++` as well.

Comment: @Tafari, that's because of how you setup the boundaries. But I'm not convinced those are necessary either. You'd need `\b ... \B`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It's not my question, and yes the problem is related to the boundries, the closing one to be precise, it's better to use just whitespace `\s` instead of `\b`.

Comment: @Tafari,LOL, my apologies friend! I really need to get through this cup of coffee faster!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud No problem, have a good one ; )

Answer (score 3):

You should use `\B` on the 2nd boundary instead of `\b`

```
MatchCollection matches= Regex.Matches(@"This  program is written in C# We'll delete it after ten days", @"\bC\#\B");
```

You can read the following link for more info :
http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is correct but its not fitting into my requirement if I change my input text to "This  program is written inC#We'll delete it after ten days" then it should not match since I need to match complete word only

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is correct but its not fitting into my requirement if I change my input text to MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(@"This  program is written in Microsoft visual basic delete it after ten days", @"\bMicrosoft\ visual\ basic\B");

Answer (score 1):

You could use following pattern, which store match in the **group 1**:

**PATTERN**

```
\bC(\+\+|\#)\s
```

And this C# code:

**CODE**

```
MatchCollection matches= Regex.Matches(@"This  program is written in C# We'll delete it after ten days", @"\bC\+\+\b");

foreach(Match m in matches)
{
     Console.Write(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

**INPUT**

```
This  program is written in C# We'll delete it after ten days
```

**OUTPUT**

```
C#
```

And

**INPUT**

```
This  program is written in C++ We'll delete it after ten days
```

**OUTPUT**

```
C++
```

Answer (score 0):

> Below code work for all my word collection except for c++ and C#

For that match to work you'd need a Regex like this `@"(?:C\+\+)|(?:C#)"` and here is a [Regex 101 to prove it](http://regex101.com/r/xK2pV4).

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, rather than looking for a **word boundary** (`\b`) or a **non-word boundary** (`\B`), you might instead consider looking for **whitespace** (`\s+`), **beginning of the line** (`^`), and **end of the line** (`$`).

Here's a regex that will do that:

```
(?:^|\s+)(C#|C\+\+)(?=\s+|$)
```

And here's a **Perl** program that demonstrates that regex on a sample data set. (Also see the [live demo](http://ideone.com/un6032).)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

#   A - Preceded by the beginning of the line or 1 or more whitespace
#       characters
#   B - The character sequences 'C#' or 'C++'
#   C - Followed by 1 or more whitespace characters or the end of line.

    if (/(?:^|\s+)(C#|C\+\+)(?=\s+|$)/) {
#           ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^
#             A        B         C

        print "[$1] [$_]\n";
    } else {
        print "[--] [$_]\n";
    }
}

__END__
This program is written in C++ We'll delete it after ten days
This program is written in !C++ We'll delete it after ten days
This program is written in C++! We'll delete it after ten days
This program is written in C# We'll delete it after ten days
C# is the language this program is written in.
 C# is the language this program is written in.
C++ is the language this program is written in.
This program is written in C#
This program is written in C++
This program is written in C++!
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[C++] [This program is written in C++ We'll delete it after ten days]
[--] [This program is written in !C++ We'll delete it after ten days]
[--] [This program is written in C++! We'll delete it after ten days]
[C#] [This program is written in C# We'll delete it after ten days]
[C#] [C# is the language this program is written in.]
[C#] [ C# is the language this program is written in.]
[C++] [C++ is the language this program is written in.]
[C#] [This program is written in C#]
[C++] [This program is written in C++]
[--] [This program is written in C++!]
```